# Unique solution to ODE for $y'(t) = f(t, y(t))$ where $f$ is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions

Let be $f : [0, T] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ partially differentiable for the both variables **and** :

\begin{equation*}
\forall (t, x) \in [0, T] \times \mathbb{R}, \left \lvert \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, x) \right \rvert \leq C
\end{equation*}

If I take a look to the classical ODE: $y'(t) = f(t, y(t))$ and $y(0) = y_0$, I'd like to know if there is a unique solution defined over $[0, T]$ to this problem.

I want the solution to be **continuous**.

So here's what I've done so far:

First, this hypothesis give me a uniform Lipschitz constant for the second variable.

This gives me a way to find almost everywhere (i.e. discontinuous over a null set) continuous over a neighborhood of $0$ using Caratheodory's theorem, plus, this solution is unique, again by Caratheodory.
Plus, $y$ would be absolutely continuous, thus, continuous.

**My question**, can I get it over $[0, T]$ completely for any arbitrary $T$?

What would be awesome is, could I even go further and **get the fact that $f$ is continuous**?

My idea is the following, if I can use the fact that $f(t, \cdot)$ is uniformly $C$-Lipschitz for all $t$.
By [Uniform Lipshitz continuity implies Continuous Differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2534942/uniform-lipshitz-continuity-implies-continuous-differentiability?rq=1) I'd get that $f(t, \cdot)$ is continuously differentiable, thus: the partial derivative is **continuous**.

But I'm suspicious, the result seems to indicate that the derivative is $0$-Holder, i.e. just bounded. A bounded real derivative is not really continuous, is it? But let's do this assumption that I have the fact that this particular partial derivative is continuous (I might find another way to prove it.)
Except if I use something else than a constant polynomial, maybe, I could have a degree 2 polynomial, but I have no idea what I could use, the second derivative is not guaranteed to exist. It could be there is some property I could use I don't see or I could just resort to weaker derivatives (?).

But, by [Partial derivatives of $f$ exist, but only $n-1$ of them are continuous, implies differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899964/partial-derivatives-of-f-exist-but-only-n-1-of-them-are-continuous-implies) ; I'd get the fact that $f$ is differentiable, thus **continuous**.

As a result, I get the solution of the ODE for free using classical Cauchy-Lipschitz. I might be wrong though with my reasoning.